# Onde eu posso comprar minha camiseta do SOpt?

Tags: suporte, camisetas

Eu tentei achar o conteúdo aqui no site, mas a única pergunta que a contém é em relação aos que já compraram. Onde está ela?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Até onde eu sei você não pode comprar. Tinha uma lojinha virtual no passado mas agora não tem mais.

Ninguém comprou, foi enviado generosamente para quem tinha algum critério de utilização no *site*, provavelmente baseado na reputação.

Comment: :( não tenho mais objetivos na vida (ok, chega de drama :P)

Comment: Alguém teria um link da imagem da camisa ? fiquei curioso

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2455/101